# git can't find remote helper for https (but it's there)

Tags: git, https, git-remote

I installed git 1.8.5.4 from source under `$HOME/bin`. My system is SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP1 (x86_64)

After installation I cannot clone repos from https urls, getting the following error:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/apbarrero/pyrad.git                                                                                                                                                
Cloning into 'pyrad'...
fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
```

I checked that git is properly compiled against libcurl-devel and libexpat-devel packages. Then I tryed using git-remote-https installed under `$HOME/bin/libexec/git-core/` and it worked fine to connect to the same remote:

```
$ $HOME/libexec/git-core/git-remote-https https://github.com/apbarrero/pyrad.git
capabilities
fetch
option
push
check-connectivity

list
@refs/heads/master HEAD
9599cf833354793b81d2a47504826332473bcb12 refs/heads/master
1f8f2b995bb5ab55e6c6f1051ccb44875ab1e60d refs/tags/0.6
68552227901d377b513884c70d9582da0329a270 refs/tags/0.6^{}
e0cd958edc5b3aad7e31435990674e2cff4e3b7e refs/tags/0.7
c50213b2d4213f3574c1a6b454e6887a529de340 refs/tags/0.7^{}
6085deb4ee37862d65f4a26f472fa2d1894a4331 refs/tags/0.8
33902c5b3da1272a4f5930815f561b8068315ba3 refs/tags/0.8^{}
5a45639faaf1cbf7622fe47e2795d6f5a0ee6658 refs/tags/0.9
edd69b9014d7e5bbf9da203d7db9a26587756aa4 refs/tags/0.9^{}
6e3b16ed19b329be944bd1b10aa17d02eb473009 refs/tags/1.0
30beedc5c4e56a15f4025d25331515aa2a917234 refs/tags/1.0^{}
dacf4bd37aaddd3872faeb8a77c801fe3c8550cb refs/tags/1.1
4c3e2d6700947ca6ea7b3319ff52abb7029bf3be refs/tags/1.1^{}
9a7f5a4e9fe19ef9f45db4e28a7d4648a011cc9b refs/tags/1.2
ee7ec8f2b37da5e84bf0fbb83e214a8bd3cfdf70 refs/tags/1.2^{}
e16af24d814e8d8c83b172ca6103fd3ab93b08db refs/tags/2.0
ce4a625caf5c6d892e020ec150373043a203366e refs/tags/2.0^{}
```

So I guess it's an installation problem. Any clue on how git locates remote helpers installed in the system?

Comment: Do you have curl-devel library installed on the system?

Comment: Yes, it's already stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had `GIT_EXEC_PATH` pointing to an NFS directory where an older version of git-core binaries was installed, just unsetting the env variable makes git installation under `$HOME/bin` work.